# Determining which members of a set are an integeral multiple of a member of a different set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm given two sets with a regular formula for the terms of each set.

$A=\left\{3,7,15,31,\cdots,2^{(n+1)}-1,\cdots,2047\right\}$

$B=\left\{3,5,9,17,\cdots,2^n+1,\cdots,2^{22}+1\right\}$

The question asks to find the sum of all distinct members of $B$ that are integral multiples of at least one member of $A$.

I noticed that every other member of $B$ is divisible by 3, although I would be interested in a mathematical way to explain why $2^{(2n+1)}+1$ is always divisible by 3. However, there's still the question of if any other members of $B$ are divisible by the other members of $A$.

Comment: what you observed is true because : $2^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \implies 2^{2n} \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \implies 2^{2n} \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \implies 2^{2n+1}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: What ideas have you learned which might be useful for this question? Do you, for example, understand any of $4^n\equiv 1 \bmod 3$?

Comment: @MarkBennet I am not too familiar with modular congruence. I understand now that $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Longrightarrow 4^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ When I repeat this with $\pmod 7$, $\pmod {15}$, and so on, it only yields $4$. Since $4\cdot 2 + 1 = 9$ and $9\pmod {(2^{(n+1)}-1)}$ never equals zero when n>1, would it be safe to assume that only members of $B$ when $n$ is odd are multiples of at least one member of $A$ (which would be $3$)?